# RecycleView Skipping layout android in parser

Tags: java, android

This is my code :

```
if(integer == 1) {
    MyAdapater adapter = new MyAdapater(c,names);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I set this in my main activity :

```
rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvSearch);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added all these below code in onCreate() means main thread.

```
 csRecyclerView  = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    csAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    //manager.setReverseLayout(true);
    //manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    csRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    csRecyclerView.setAdapter(csAdapter);
```

and check the count of recycler item in

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //you can pass ur server response array here
        //int count = (csMainJsonArr != null) ? csMainJsonArr.length() : 0;
        int count = 20;
        return count;
    }
```

I think in your case you only you need to set adapter inside if condition.

```
 if(integer == 1) {
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```